# Swinject returns nil because object is wrong registered

Tags: ios, swift, swinject

This is how I register object for `FirebaseMessaging`:

```
    container.register(Messaging.self) { _ in
        return Messaging.messaging()
    }
```

and then I need to use it:

```
    container.register(NotificationSchedulerable.self) { resolver in
        let userNotificationCenter = resolver.resolve(UNUserNotificationCenter.self)!
        let messaging = resolver.resolve(Messaging.self)! //unexpectadly found nil
        return NotificationScheduler(userNotificationCenter: userNotificationCenter, messaging: messaging)
    }
```

But I receive an error:

> Swinject: Resolution failed. Expected registration:
> { Service: FIRMessaging, Factory: Resolver -> FIRMessaging }
> Available registrations:
> { Service: FIRMessaging, Factory: Resolver -> FIRMessaging, ObjectScope: graph }
> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file ToolsAssembly.swift, line 72

Why it happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem is that you have to register a FIRMessaging instead Messaging

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client?hl=es

Like this:

```
    container.register(FIRMessaging.self) { _ in
        return Messaging.messaging()
    }
```

And then:

```
container.register(NotificationSchedulerable.self) { resolver in
        let userNotificationCenter = resolver.resolve(UNUserNotificationCenter.self)!
        let messaging = resolver.resolve(FIRMessaging.self)! //unexpectadly found nil
        return NotificationScheduler(userNotificationCenter: userNotificationCenter, messaging: messaging)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Could I invite you to check a new fresh [DIContainer](https://github.com/Tavernari/DIContainer) for Swift?

In this lib, you can access your dependencies using a property wrapper.

```
@Injected(.githubService)
var githubService: FetchService

@Injected(.by(type: FetchService.self, withKey: "gitlab"))
var gitlabService: FetchService

@InjectedSafe
var externalService: ExternalSingletonService?
```

I hope it fits well with your necessities.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `FirebaseApp.configure()` before resolving your dependencies.